# Does the latest version of CentOS support Secure Boot?

Tags: centos

I have a Dell XPS 15 9570. I want to dual boot centOS alongside Windows 10. Does centOS support Secure Boot? Should I enable or disable Secure Boot in the UEFI setting?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It does support secure boot but with some [conditions](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/UEFIandSecureBoot) on architectures.
Only, `x86_64` architecture supports secure boot with **UEFI** (CentOS 7).